# jQuery clone form with empty input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a form that I wanted to clone this form every time the ADD button clicked. in this case form appended with previous values for inputs. I want each form work separately. Is there a way to append with empty values for inputs?

Here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Add").click(function() {
    $(".formi").eq(0).clone().show().insertAfter(".formi:last");
    
  });
  $('.all').on('click', ".cancel", function() {
      $(this).closest('.formi').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
  <form class="formi">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Sarah" />
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="one">one</option>
      <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">ok</button>
    <span class="cancel">Cancel</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just clear them in the cloned copy (see `***` line):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Add").click(function() {
    $(".formi")
      .eq(0)
      .clone()
      .find("input").val("").end() // ***
      .show()
      .insertAfter(".formi:last");
    
  });
  $('.all').on('click', ".cancel", function() {
      $(this).closest('.formi').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
  <form class="formi">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Sarah" />
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="one">one</option>
      <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">ok</button>
    <span class="cancel">Cancel</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

That specific example uses [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to find the `input`, [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) to clear its value, and then [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end) to return to the original set of cloned elements so that `show` and `insertAfter` are run on that set (instead of the input(s)).

Comment: it works only for input but the values of select boxes are still exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should first clone the `form` and then reset the element values as follows. In your case `input`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Add").click(function() {

    var form = $(".formi").eq(0).clone();
    form.find("input[type=text]").val("");
    form.show().insertAfter(".formi:last");


  });
  $('.all').on('click', ".cancel", function() {
    $(this).closest('.formi').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
  <form class="formi">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Sarah" />
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="one">one</option>
      <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">ok</button>
    <span class="cancel">Cancel</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select the last form after the clone then empty the value of the child inputs like :

```
$(".formi:last input").val('');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Add").click(function() {
    $(".formi").eq(0).clone().show().insertAfter(".formi:last");
    $(".formi:last input").val('');
  });
  $('.all').on('click', ".cancel", function() {
    $(this).closest('.formi').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
  <form class="formi">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Sarah" />
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="one">one</option>
      <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">ok</button>
    <span class="cancel">Cancel</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored some of your stuff because I had to do it differently in order to make it work the way i wanted it to, but here it is.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michael_coder/ojheepjz/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js">           </script>
  <span class="Add">Add+</span>
  <div class="all">
  <div class="formi">
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Sarah" />
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
  </select>
  <button class="add">ok</button>
  <span class="cancel">Cancel</span>
    </div>
</div>   



function addClickListener(){
    arr = $(".add")
    $(arr[arr.length - 1]).click(function(ev) {
      var clone = ev.currentTarget.parentElement.cloneNode(true);
      $('.all').append(clone);
      addClickListener();

    });
    cancArr = $('.cancel');
    $(cancArr[cancArr.length - 1])
    .on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
  }

  addClickListener();
```