# Clone a form with a click of a button

Tags: javascript, forms, clone

i have this form and button in my html page:
[image]

All i want is to when i click this button a new (but same) empty form to appear next to the one that already exists.

I tried this:

```
let clone = $("#nfa-transitions .production-row").last().clone(true);
```

but the new form that appears is not empty, it has the previous data!

Does anyone know how can i do it?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/): _"Note: For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the cloned elements."_ -> `.find()` the `<input>` elements and reset their value before you append the form to the DOM.

Comment: Add some code to the question to make it easier for people to help u. This is just not good enough

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery clone form with empty input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262488/jquery-clone-form-with-empty-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
$("#add").click(function(){
  var clone = $("#nfa-transitions .production-row").last().clone(true);
  clone.val("");
  clone.find("input").each(function() {
      $(this).val("");
  });
  clone.appendTo($("#production-rows"));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="nfa-transitions">
  <div id="production-rows">
    <div class="production-row">
    ( <input type="number" >, <input type="number" > ) = <input type="number" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="add" value="Click here to add a new transition">
</form>
```